# Issue: Violation of Permissions policy from google console

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-permissions

Publishing status:

> Rejected
>
> After review, your app has been rejected and wasn't published due to a policy violation. If you submitted an update, the previous version of your app is still available on Google Play.
>
> Issue:
>
> Violation of Permissions policy   After reviewing your app, we found that it doesn’t qualify to use the requested permissions for the following reason(s):
>
> Based on our review, we found your app’s expressed user experience did not match your declared core functionality Default SMS handler (and any other core functionality usage while default handler). Please remove these permissions from your app.
>
> Default handler capability was listed on your declaration form, but your app does not appear to have default handler capability. Please submit a revised declaration form.
>
> Your app needs to use runtime permissions for us to complete the review. Please update your app to target API level 26 or above. If you have APKs in different tracks of the app releases section of your Play Console, please deactivate non-compliant APKs before submitting your app again. For additional guidance, please review the documentation on how to request app permissions.

I have already implemented SMS Retriever functionality and removed all SMS permissions and Call log permissions also.

using only permission related to Call & Phone are:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" /> 

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS"
    tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.example.nyros.myapplication.C2D_MESSAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_DOCUMENTS"
    tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.example.googlemaps.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
<!-- <service android:name=".DownloadService"/> -->

<permission
    android:name="com.example.googlemaps.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<permission
    android:name="com.aquadeals.partner.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />
```

Do i need to remove any of the above mentioned manifest permissions or do i need to check any issues in the process of submitting APK to play console?

Comment: Retain your old version when release your new version.

Comment: i didn't get your answer,Can  you please explain in detail.? @Gökberk Yağcı

Comment: When you new release to production you need to retain old version on "Android App Bundles and APKs to deactivate" section. Its play console bug.
https://imgur.com/xXrnDHj

Comment: Okay but what should i do to make my app live now.It was in unpublished state for Violation of Permissions policy from google console.

Answer (score 0):

Don’t use CALL_PHONE permission, use Dialer intent instead.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:0123456789"));
startActivity(intent);
```